# save page in c# webbrowser without savefiledialogue

Tags: c#

I'm using `C#` web browser and I want to save some of pages when a key is pressed but when I use SaveFileDialgue a window pop ups and asks for destination! Is there any way to save it directly to a specific destination without prompting me?

here it is my code:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
  SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
  sfd.Filter = " TEXT File |*.txt";
  if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    browser.SaveDocument(sfd.FileName);
  }        
}
```

Comment: Have you observed that your code is calling a method called `ShowDialog`?

Comment: yes but i dont have any idea how to call it without showdialog, i mean give it a default path and it save's it there without asking user

Comment: You are asking how to save the document without showing a dialog when your code clearly says, in plain English, that you are *showing a dialog to the user* and then *saving the document*.

Answer (score 1):

remove the following lines

```
 SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = " TEXT File |*.txt";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                browser.SaveDocument(sfd.FileName);
            }
```

add

```
 browser.SaveDocument("c:\\outputfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the page using

```
private void BtnSaveHtml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog();
            string html;

            html = webBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString();
        }
```

and with the help of stream writer you save all the data where you want to save.